# Order of executation for SignIn and SignUp methods with Spring-Social

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-mvc, twitter, spring-social

In my current spring project, I recently added support for social signin using the Spring-Social. The main configuration class it's this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
@ComponentScan(value="com.webapp.loja")
public class SocialContext implements SocialConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private SignInAdapter signInAdapter;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionSignUp connectionSignUp;

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory("...", "..."));
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory("...", "..."));
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        JdbcUsersConnectionRepository repository = new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator, Encryptors.noOpText()); 
        repository.setConnectionSignUp(connectionSignUp);
        return repository;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        return new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository, signInAdapter);
    }

}
```

My problem it's that when i try signin in the application with any of the social media services, the application execute firts the `connectionSignUp` class, and after the `signInAdapter`.

I want the oposite behavior: first the application should execute `signInAdapter`, where I try find if the user already exists:

```
@Service
public class SimpleSignInAdapter implements SignInAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SocialUserDetailsService socialUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    public String signIn(String userId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {
        SocialUserDetails user = socialUserDetailsService.loadUserByUserId(userId);
        if(user != null) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities()));
            return user.getUsername();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

only if no user is found (null is returned), the applications should execute the `connectionSignUp` class to create a new account:

```
@Component
public class AccountConnectionSignUp implements ConnectionSignUp {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioHome accountRepository;

    @Override
    public String execute(Connection<?> connection) {
        UserProfile profile = connection.fetchUserProfile();
        Usuario account = new Usuario(profile.getUsername(), profile.getFirstName(), profile.getLastName(), profile.getEmail());
        accountRepository.persist(account);
        return profile.getUsername();
    }

}
```

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,the ordering sounds ok to me? In the connectionSignUp, you can check to see if user is already persisted. If yes, move on and sign the user in. If not, register the user. Then sign him in?